# Как создавать настраиваемые блоки с информацией в C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не знаю как правильно написать определение, но сейчас расскажу в чём суть. **Я хочу** создавать блоки параметров иерархически (хотя вернее наверное будет сказать по классам). Вот например, у меня есть 3 разных героя, 20 разных видов оружия и у каждого свои параметры. И я хочу делать что бы были удобные блоки что бы я мог ссылаться например при каком то триггере что бы менялся персонаж или оружие, без постоянных "if-else". **Что я хочу узнать** - через что это лучше реализовать или как правильно указать нужную информацию и в целом как это называется о чём я говорю

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужно познакомится с ООП, в частности с наледованием и полиморфизмом

Comment: Спасибо солнце!<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Что я хочу узнать - через что это лучше реализовать или как правильно указать нужную информацию и в целом как это называется о чём я говорю" - это называется объектно-ориентированное проектирование.

Классический труд на эту тему:
[Гради Буч. Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование с примерами приложений на С++](https://coollib.com/b/198321-gradi-buch-obektno-orientirovannyiy-analiz-i-proektirovanie-s-primerami-prilozheniy-na-s/read)

Comment: Спасибо солнце, теперь знаю куда развится <3